# .nd2 to .tif using fiji bio-formats windowless

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro, fiji

thanks for stopping by.

I am trying to process ~50 images from .nd2 to .TIF, but the exported images are not what I expect and I'm not sure what is wrong. My .nd2's have two channels and I would like the final .TIF to be an image of both channels. However, the .TIF output of my code is an image of just one channel.

```
setBatchMode(true); //Batch mode processing setting in ImageJ
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    showProgress(i+1, list.length);
    filename = list[i];
    setBatchMode(true); // prevents image windows from opening while the script is running
    run("Bio-Formats Windowless Importer", "open=[" + dir1 + filename +"] autoscale color_mode=Composite rois_import=[ROI manager] view=DataBrowser stack_order=XYCZT");

    selectWindow(filename);
    run("Stack to RGB", "slices"); // convert to RGB stack
```

...after this part of code I split the z-stack, find the middle, and save that slice as a .TIFF.

Please let me know if anything isn't clear. Thanks again for reading.

Comment: This question is better asked on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) where you're more likely to get help quickly, from those who know ImageJ and also Bio-Formats well.

Comment: thanks, Jan! I've posted it on the ImageJ forum.

Comment: For the record: this question was discussed and answered [here](https://forum.image.sc/t/problems-with-nd2-to-tif-using-fiji-macro/12066?u=imagejan) on the ImageJ.sc forum.